# In Safari, is there any keyboard shortcut to *hide* the Web Inspector?

Tags: safari

In Safari, when the Develop menu is enabled, I can make the Web Inspector appear by hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>. However, when I hit that again, the Web Inspector stays where it is.

Is there any way I can hide it with another (or somehow the same) keyboard shortcut?

Comment: You could detach it from the Safari window. It seems that Safari remembers this choice, although it doesn't remember the position of the detached window. Then you can close it with CMD-W.

Comment: @nathang: sure, that’s a decent workaround. Personally, I can’t be doing with my inspector in a separate window (confuses the heck out of me), but it’s worth considering.

Comment: You might be able to add your own by scripting Accessibility, but I'm no expert on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the apple website, there is no hide shortcut. Sorry.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=42951

Sorry.